# struct has a function pointer to a function that takes a pointer of said struct .. need to predfine?

Tags: c, prototype, struct, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to create a structure, that has a function pointer. That function pointer points to a function, that takes a pointer of said structure.  This is a real chicken-or-the-egg problem because the prototype needs to know about the structure and the structure needs to know about the prototype.  Is there a way to predefine the struct?  I'm new to C so if anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
-devnull

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* predefine struct person? */
void printInfo(struct person *);

struct person{
char *name;
int age;
const void *pf = printInfo;
};


int main(){

struct person master = {"Master", 23};  
return 0;
}

void printInfo(struct person *p){

printf("Name:\t%s\n", p->name);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct person;

typedef void (*fp)(struct person*);

struct person {
    char * name;
    fp fptr;
};

void afunc( struct person * p ) {
    // stuff
}

int main() {
      struct person p = { "fred", afunc };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `struct person;` before the function, but you cannot assign the function in struct person as far as I know,

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct person;
typedef void (FUNCTYPE)(struct person *);
void printInfo(struct person *);

struct person{
    char *name;
    int age;
    FUNCTYPE *pf;
};


int main(){

struct person master = {"Master", 23, printInfo};
    (master.pf)(&master);
    return 0;
}

void printInfo(struct person *p){
    printf("Name:\t%s\n", p->name);
}
```

The example above prints `Name: Master`

Comment: @pmg - there is such a library, it's called libMByD. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks very much, but why do i need to typedef? can't i just have the function pointer declaration be: void (*pf)();

Comment: because you want a pointer to function returns void, not a pointer to void. And in general, if you want a pointer to function, you need to define the function prototype so you won't have incompatible types, the compiler need to know what to do when you call a function, and thats your way to tell him what does the function expects as parameters and what does it return.

Comment: The use of typedef is in order to avoid long unclear definition such as `void (*pf)(struct master)` instead of `FUNCTYPE *pf`

Comment: @afulldevnull - you can see a small tutorial about that here: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13829

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would add is that all struct pointers have the same width and alignment (6.2.5/27 (C99 Standard)), so you don't actually require the forward definition of the struct.